# Change Windows Lock Screen background image in C#

Tags: c#, windows-8

Is there a way to change the lock screen image like the wall paper in c# using pinvoke.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern Int32 SystemParametersInfo(UInt32 action,
        UInt32 uParam, string vParam, UInt32 winIni);
private static readonly UInt32 SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20;
private static UInt32 SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x1;
private static uint MAX_PATH = 260;

// then I call
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, file, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

I'd like to do the same for the lockscreen (like the Bing Desktop app is doing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your Windows 8-tag, yes you can:

[`LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701552.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), as demonstrated on [Lock screen personalization sample in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/personalization/) (error handling code omitted, check the sample):

```
StorageFile imageFile = await imagePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

// Application now has access to the picked file, setting image to lockscreen.  
// This will fail if the file is an invalid format.
await LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync(imageFile);
```

Comment: Actually, I have done it like that. But it worked the first time, and now nothing happens...

Comment: OK, after some research this code works fine if I chose x64 but not anyCPU... Do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: @Swell no idea, sorry.